# How to query and filter on a List of objects type data stored on dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a list named "A" which stores a list of objects. Each object will be something like this,

```
"A" : [
    {
        "B" : "aaaaa",
        "C" : "sssss"
    },
    {
        "B" : "asasa",
        "C" : "sasas"
    }
]
```

How would I query and filter these objects held by A? I have tried the following KeyCondition Expressions,

```
" A[*].B = 'aaaaaa' "

" A.B = 'aaaaaa' "
```

But none of it does what I like to do.

**EDIT 1:**

Using "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb" v1.11.31

Query Spec is built as below,

```
QuerySpec query = new QuerySpec().withHashKey("user_name", "disney")
                                 .withFilterExpression("A[*].B = :value")
                                 .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                                 .withString(":value","aaaaa"));
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> = table.query(query);
```

Comment: It would be very useful if you say what language/SDK you're using and the code you've tried so far (including the API name, such as BatchGetItem...etc)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, there is no way to accomplish what I was trying to do. I ended up writing loop which generated the filter expressions I needed and I was querying multiple times to accomplish this.

Comment: can you provide your solution with example